# ^SMMEMFULL:"RAM" error message in HUAWEI K2540 dongle

Tags: serial-port, at-command, dongle, huawei-mobile-services

After receiving a number of +CMT messages (around 20-30, not sure) into TE (Terminal Equipment) I get this error: `^SMMEMFULL:"RAM"` and will no longer see the incoming SMS messages, the same error comes instead of each SMS message.

[image]

My Modem configurations are a below:

```
> AT&F 
> AT+CMGF=1 
> AT+CNMI=1,2,0,0,0
```

After doing my research on the net I found and tried the following commands with no avail:

```
 - ATZ
 - AT^CURC=0;^PORTSEL=1
 - AT+ZRST //not supported command
 - AT+ZSNT=0,0,0//not supported
 - AT+CNMI=1,2,0,0,1 (last parameter clears the buffer)
 - AT+CPMS="ME","ME","ME"\n AT+CMGD=1,4
```

I also checked this link:

http://users.kannel.narkive.com/yO1t7yuF/smmemfull-ram-and-not-receiving-messages

**Expected behavior:**
I am going to read only once every message that my Huawei dongle is receiving, thus my dongle needs to stay on for days, therefore it has to handle thousands of SMS messages without encountering any type of "Memory Full" error messages.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. I solved it by removing the drivers and software of my dongle. Then, I reinstall them. It works. To remove drivers go to Device Manager -> remove the drivers of COM ports, then remove the drivers of USB ports of your dongle. After that, Restart your computer, Then install your dongle software again. it will work fine.